# spark selecting and filtering inside aggregation

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Step 1: Generate DS

```
testDf = sparkSession.createDataFrame(
    [
        ['collection_1', 'i1,i2,i3,i4', '1590383291000'],
        ['collection_2', 'i2,i5,i6', '1590469691000'],
        ['collection_3', 'i1,i2', '1590556091000'],
        ['collection_4', 'i3', '1590642491000']
    ]
    , ["collection_id", "item_ids", "ts"]
)
```

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|collection_id|   item_ids|           ts|
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| collection_1|i1,i2,i3,i4|1590383291000|
| collection_2|   i2,i5,i6|1590469691000|
| collection_3|      i1,i2|1590556091000|
| collection_4|         i3|1590642491000|
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Step 2: Intermediate Step -> 
Explode using `item_ids` , the group by `item_id` and create a reverse mapping

```
explodedDf = testDf.select(
        "collection_id",
        f.split("item_ids", ",").alias('item_ids'),
        f.posexplode(f.split("item_ids", ",")).alias("pos", "item_id"),
        "ts"
    )
```

```
+-------------+----------------+---+-------+-------------+                      
|collection_id|        item_ids|pos|item_id|           ts|
+-------------+----------------+---+-------+-------------+
| collection_1|[i1, i2, i3, i4]|  0|     i1|1590383291000|
| collection_1|[i1, i2, i3, i4]|  1|     i2|1590383291000|
| collection_1|[i1, i2, i3, i4]|  2|     i3|1590383291000|
| collection_1|[i1, i2, i3, i4]|  3|     i4|1590383291000|
| collection_2|    [i2, i5, i6]|  0|     i2|1590469691000|
| collection_2|    [i2, i5, i6]|  1|     i5|1590469691000|
| collection_2|    [i2, i5, i6]|  2|     i6|1590469691000|
| collection_3|        [i1, i2]|  0|     i1|1590556091000|
| collection_3|        [i1, i2]|  1|     i2|1590556091000|
| collection_4|            [i3]|  0|     i3|1590642491000|
+-------------+----------------+---+-------+-------------+
```

```
explodedDf.groupBy("item_id").agg(f.max("ts").alias("latest_ts"),f.collect_set("collection_id").alias("collection_ids"), f.max("item_ids").alias("item_ids")).show(10)
```

```
+-------+-------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+
|item_id|latest_ts    |collection_ids                            |item_ids        |
+-------+-------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+
|i3     |1590642491000|[collection_1, collection_4]              |[i3]            |
|i5     |1590469691000|[collection_2]                            |[i2, i5, i6]    |
|i1     |1590556091000|[collection_3, collection_1]              |[i1, i2, i3, i4]|
|i6     |1590469691000|[collection_2]                            |[i2, i5, i6]    |
|i2     |1590556091000|[collection_3, collection_1, collection_2]|[i2, i5, i6]    |
|i4     |1590383291000|[collection_1]                            |[i1, i2, i3, i4]|
+-------+-------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Step 3 -> Expected output

Instead of performing the aggregation `f.collect_set("collection_id")` , I want to only select 
the collection_id which has the latest `ts` .

for column `collection_ids`

- [collection_1, collection_4] -> show only [collection_4] as it has the latest ts (ref. step 1)
- [collection_2] -> show [collection_2]
- [collection_3, collection_1] -> show only [collection_3] as it has the latest ts
- [collection_2] -> show [collection_2]
- [collection_3, collection_1, collection_2] -> show only [collection_3] as it has the latest ts
- [collection_1] -> show [collection_1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a window over `item_id` after `explode` and then `filter` , starting from your original df, you can try below:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("item_id")

output = testDf.select(
        "collection_id",
        F.split("item_ids", ",").alias('item_ids'),
        F.explode(F.split("item_ids", ",")).alias("item_id"),
        "ts"
    ).withColumn("latest_ts",F.max("ts").over(w)).filter("ts==latest_ts").drop("ts")

output.select(*['item_id','latest_ts','collection_id','item_ids']).show()
```

---

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|item_id|    latest_ts|collection_id|        item_ids|
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|     i3|1590642491000| collection_4|            [i3]|
|     i5|1590469691000| collection_2|    [i2, i5, i6]|
|     i1|1590556091000| collection_3|        [i1, i2]|
|     i6|1590469691000| collection_2|    [i2, i5, i6]|
|     i2|1590556091000| collection_3|        [i1, i2]|
|     i4|1590383291000| collection_1|[i1, i2, i3, i4]|
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```